# ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch: Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a Set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

> `ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch`: `Attribute` was supposed to be a `Array`, but was a `Set`

in Task.all

Unable to fetch all records.

This issue is in `fat_free_crm` open source application available in Ruby on Rails.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Which version of rails and ruby are you using?

Comment: ruby version 2.3.1